Integrating vue into existing shopify theme
I have an existing shopify theme from symmetry and I would like to include vue for state management. I followed the docs and everything but im getting errors such as:

And it prevents my other components from loading on the page. I get why its complaining since some of the sections in the theme contain inline scripts like:
{% style %}
      {%- if section.settings.autoplay -%}
        #section-id-{{ section.id }} slide-show {
          --duration: {{ section.settings.autoplay_speed }}s;
          --play-state: paused;
        }
      {%- endif -%}

      {%- if section.settings.height == 'fixed' %}
        #section-id-{{ section.id }} .height--fixed {
          --image-height: {{ section.settings.height_mobile }}px;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
          #section-id-{{ section.id }} .height--fixed {
            --image-height: {{ section.settings.height_desktop }}px;
          }
        }
      {%- endif -%}

      {%- if section.settings.height == 'adapt' %}
        #section-id-{{ section.id }} .height--adapt {
          {%- if section.blocks.first.settings.mobile_image -%}
            --aspect-ratio: {{ section.blocks.first.settings.mobile_image.aspect_ratio }};
          {%- else -%}
            --aspect-ratio: {{ section.blocks.first.settings.image.aspect_ratio | default: 2.0 }};
          {%- endif -%}
        }
        {%- if section.blocks.first.settings.mobile_image -%}
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
          #section-id-{{ section.id }} .height--adapt {
            --aspect-ratio: {{ section.blocks.first.settings.image.aspect_ratio | default: 2.0 }};
          }
        }
        {%- endif -%}
      {%- endif -%}

      {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
        #section-id-{{ section.id }} .slide-{{ forloop.index }} .text-overlay__title {
          font-size: {{ block.settings.title_size_mobile }}px;
          {%- if block.settings.title_size_mobile >= 90 -%}
          line-height: 1em;
          {%- endif %}
        }
      {%- endfor -%}

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
        #section-id-{{ section.id }} .slide-{{ forloop.index }} .text-overlay__title {
          {%- assign title_size_medium = block.settings.title_size | times: 0.7 | at_least: block.settings.title_size_mobile -%}
          font-size: {{ title_size_medium }}px;
          {%- if title_size_medium >= 90 -%}
          line-height: 1em;
          {%- endif %}
        }
        {%- endfor -%}
      }

      @media (min-width: 1100px) {
        {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
        #section-id-{{ section.id }} .slide-{{ forloop.index }} .text-overlay__title {
          font-size: {{ block.settings.title_size }}px;
          {%- if block.settings.title_size >= 90 -%}
          line-height: 1em;
          {%- endif %}
        }
        {%- endfor -%}
      }
    {% endstyle %}

How do I fix or bypass these issues? I really dont want to change code that came with the theme.
I dont get these errors if I do
 <div id="app"> 
   </div>

 <main id="content" role="main">
        <div class="container cf">
          {{ content_for_layout }}
        </div>
      </main>

vs
 <div id="app"> 
      <main id="content" role="main">
        <div class="container cf">
          {{ content_for_layout }}
        </div>
      </main>
   </div>

But I need sections in content for layout to have access to the vue instance.

Those are not errors but warnings. The issue looks like this script that you're loading thanks to <script src>.

Im considering it an error since its preventing my shopify components from loading on the page. If I remove vue it works fine. And i know the issue is the script and inline styles tag but these are everywhere in this theme. I am just looking for a way to tell vue to ignore these files completely when attempting to compile

How do you include Vue in the project? Do you import a CDN at a top level file somewhere? Is Vue complaining with such a setup?

I have tried both the cdn and using the library with lavarel-mix to compile and both had the same issue

You found nothing online regarding this warning? There is maybe a way to disable that behavior from Vue's side of have a way to white-list it properly.

Yea I found nothing that helped so far that is why i turned to stackoverflow.
